# How to read woocommerce product attribute by if condition

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to write a if condition for WordPress Woocommerce PHP read a text line if For a specific word then do the condition else return false.

Here is a example what I am looking for: `cart.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Cart Page
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.3.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

wc_print_notices();

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' ); ?>

<form id="cart-table" action="<?php echo esc_url(  WC()->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table' ); ?>
<table class="shop_table cart" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="product-remove">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="product-thumbnail">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="product-name"><?php _e('Product', 'yit'); ?></th>
            <th class="product-price"><?php _e('Price', 'yit'); ?></th>
            <th class="product-quantity"><?php _e('Quantity', 'yit'); ?></th>
            <th class="product-subtotal"><?php _e('Total', 'yit'); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents' ); ?>

        <?php
            foreach (  WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $attributes = $_product->get_attributes();

                if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                    ?>
                    <tr class = "<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">

                        <td class="product-remove">
                            <?php
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf('<a href="%s" class="remove" title="%s">&times;</a>', esc_url(  WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ), __('Remove this item', 'yit') ), $cart_item_key );
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-thumbnail">
                            <?php
                            $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                            if ( ! $_product->is_visible() )
                                echo $thumbnail;
                            else
                                printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ), $thumbnail );
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-name">
                            <?php
                            if ( ! $_product->is_visible() )
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                            else
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ), $_product->get_title() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                                // Meta data  Remove 'lala' from echo here by Rupom
                                echo  ''. WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item );

                                // Backorder notification
                                if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) )
                                    echo '<p class="backorder_notification">' . __('Available on backorder', 'yit') . '</p>';
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-price">
                            <?php
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                            ?>
                        </td>

        <td class="product-quantity">

            <?php

            if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
            }


            elseif ( $_product->is_type('simple') ){ 
            $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                    'input_name'  => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                    'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
                    'max_value'   => $_product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $_product->get_stock_quantity(),
                    'min_value'   => '0'
                ), $_product, false );
            }

            elseif(isset($attributes['Color'])){
                  $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                          'input_name'  => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                          'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
                          'max_value'   => $_product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $_product->get_stock_quantity(),
                          'min_value'   => '0'
                        ), $_product, false );

                  }else{
                  $product_quantity = sprintf( '<input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
                  } 


            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key );
            ?>
        </td>

                        <td class="product-subtotal">
                            <?php
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            }

        do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_contents' );
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6" class="actions">

                <?php if ( WC()->cart->coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
                    <div class="coupon">

                        <label for="coupon_code"><?php _e('Coupon', 'yit'); ?>:</label> <input name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" /> <input type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php _e('Apply Coupon', 'yit'); ?>" />

                        <?php do_action('woocommerce_cart_coupon'); ?>

                    </div>
                <?php } ?>

                <input type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="<?php _e('Update Cart', 'yit'); ?>" /> <input type="submit" class="checkout-button button alt" name="proceed" value="<?php _e('Proceed to Checkout &rarr;', 'yit'); ?>" />

                <?php do_action('woocommerce_cart_actions'); ?>

                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart') ?>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_contents' ); ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_table' ); ?>
</form>
<div class="cart-collaterals row-fluid">
<?php do_action('woocommerce_cart_collaterals'); ?>
<?php //woocommerce_cart_totals(); ?>
<?php woocommerce_shipping_calculator(); ?>
</div>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart' ); ?>
```

SEE THE QUANTITY :

```
<td class="product-quantity">

            <?php

            if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
            }


            elseif ( $_product->is_type('simple') ){ 
            $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                    'input_name'  => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                    'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
                    'max_value'   => $_product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $_product->get_stock_quantity(),
                    'min_value'   => '0'
                ), $_product, false );
            }

            elseif(isset($attributes['Color'])){
                  $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                          'input_name'  => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                          'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
                          'max_value'   => $_product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $_product->get_stock_quantity(),
                          'min_value'   => '0'
                        ), $_product, false );

                  }else{
                  $product_quantity = sprintf( '<input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
                  } 


            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key );
            ?>
        </td>
```

[image: SEE THE RESULT]
Please help. what should be the **if condition for product attribute.**

Comment: How to get product attribute from cart added product?

Comment: I have added a Image of that cart I need the Quantity field for the Color atribute

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for `isset()`:

```
if ( isset($attributes['Color']) ){
```

Or, if you're looking for a specific color:

```
if ( isset($attributes['Color']) && $attributes['Color'] == 'somecolor' ){
```

Comment: Actually I am working on a cart page of woocommerce theme. If product variable has Color attribute display quantity field else remove for all other attribute

Comment: OK...then I don't understand how this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: I have Updated the Question Please check . What I did mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a specific color then you can also use -

```
global $product;
$color = $product->get_attribute( 'Color' );
```

and then check in the `if` condition.

**EDIT:**

If you are on the cart page, then `global $product` is of no use for you. You will need to loop through array of products added to the cart and then check for attributes.

See, if the below code helps you -

```
    global $woocommerce;

    $cart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

    foreach ( $cart as $key => $values ) {
        $product = $values['data'];
        $attributes = $product->get_attributes();

        if(isset($attributes['Color'])){ //can use in_array() as well
            //Something 
        }
        else{
            //Another Something
        }
    }
```

You will need to put above code in a function and hook into a proper WooCommerce filter.

Comment: I know it works but Actually I am working on a cart page of woocommerce theme. If product variable has Color attribute display quantity field else remove the quantity field for all other attribute

Comment: I have improved my answer, please check.

Comment: I have Updated the Question Please check . What I did mistake

Comment: Please help me I an confuse

Comment: If you are specifically looking to remove quantity field, then I believe you will need to override cart template for this. Via 'woocommerce_cart_item_product' filter, you can edit data and not its HTML. You can however, just hide it via CSS.

Comment: I have use your code but it return the text "array" instead of Attribute name.