# How to show product attribute name in cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

One of my favorite members [helgatheviking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383847/helgatheviking), gave me a good solution [of my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926084/how-to-remove-the-quantity-field-from-cart-page-for-specific-product-attribute-w) to remove the quantity field from cart page for specific product attribute . Below is the function given by her.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', 'remove_cart_item_quantity', 10, 2 );
function remove_cart_item_quantity( $product_quantity, $cart_item_key ){
    $cart_item = WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ];
    if( $cart_item['data']->is_type( 'variation' ) ){
        $attributes = $cart_item['data']->get_attributes();
        // var_dump( $attributes );
        if( array_key_exists( 'color', $attributes ) ){
            $product_quantity = '';
        }
    }
    return $product_quantity;
}
```

Now the `$product_quantity;` return a blank string.

Is it possible to show the name instead of Blank. `$product_quantity = '';`  What should I replace ?  If Selected product has color Green The `$product_quantity;` should return  green.
EXAMPLE:
`$product_quantity = '$color';` How could I get the color string from product attribute which in the cart.

Comment: How to show the color name

Comment: In the other question, we already discussed using the `var_dump` to see what data is available in the attributes variable.

Comment: Thanks !!! I just Solve this see below answer

Answer (score 0):

I Solve this actually `$_pname = WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item );` So you can use `$product_quantity = str_ireplace( 'Choose Quantity:', '',$_pname) ;`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', 'remove_cart_item_quantity', 10, 2 );
function remove_cart_item_quantity( $product_quantity, $cart_item_key ){
    $cart_item = WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ];
    if( $cart_item['data']->is_type( 'variation' ) ){
        $attributes = $cart_item['data']->get_attributes();
        $_pname = WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item );
        if( array_key_exists( 'choose-quantity', $attributes ) ){
            $product_quantity = str_ireplace( 'Choose Quantity:', '',$_pname) ;
        }
    }
    return $product_quantity;
}
```

**Output:**
[image: Output Cart.php]